# How to add categories and subcategories in meanjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, angularjs-directive, meanjs

I have three linked lists you need to work a bit like a cascading drop-down lists, that is, when you select an item in the first list, the second filter, which filters the third.

i need same like this.`[http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/dWqhV/][1]`

In this example all data is added static, but i need to add dynamic using module crud in meanjs.

categories controller:

```
angular.module('categories').controller('CategoriesController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Categories',
function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Categories) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;

// Create new Category
    $scope.create = function() {
        // Create new Category object
        var category = new Categories ({
            name: this.name
        });

// Redirect after save
        category.$save(function(response) {
            $location.path('categories/' + response._id);

// Clear form fields
            $scope.name = '';
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };
}
]);
```

create categories:

```
<section data-ng-controller="CategoriesController">
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>New Category</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="create()" novalidate>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
            </div>
            <div data-ng-show="error" class="text-danger">
                <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i have done how to add categories using crud modules.in that i don't now how to add subcategories and listing.

Comment: I meant you should create a fiddle or post the code you are working with.  Otherwise you are basically asking someone to write your code for you.